# openSUSE unzip unicode issue

Tags: linux, zip, unicode, opensuse

On Linux(openSUSE) machine I'm trying to deploy on Tomcat 8 application(war file) that contains a files with names with Unicode characters.

Inside of the war file the name looks like:

```
бжк-природний-1496336830201.xml
```

but after deploy the file looks like:

```
???-?????????????-1496336830201.xml
```

Also, when I manually unzip files the names are also corrupted.

How to tell unzip and Tomcat to properly deploy the file names ?

By the way - I have download this war file to my Windows machine and unzipped there - everything is looking good.

**UPDATED**

This is a sample war file with unicode file name inside: [war file](http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/files/api.war)

What is wrong with the file name of the file inside in this war ?

Comment: Normally Unix filesystems support Unicode. But the locale (or font) used in your terminal may not. Otherwise check `unzip -v`, it will tell you if it was compiled with Unicode support (mine says `UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars, char coding: UTF-8] (handle UTF-8 paths)`

Comment: yes, it has `UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars, char coding: UTF-8] (handle UTF-8 paths)`

Comment: Check you locale and terminal font then. Did you try to look at the directory using some graphical file browser (filezilla if remote and accessible with FTP or SSH)? It may show you the file names correctly.

Comment: looks like the issue is with file names itself inside the war file because I can create a non-Latin characters in the system and can see them.. How to check the file name encoding in Linux ?

Comment: I have added a sample war file to my question

Comment: If the file name is supposed to be `13я-стац_я-великого-фонтану-1496338558663.xml` then the file names in the WAR aren't in UTF-8 but in CP866 (possibly encoded twice). Not hard to fix the names on the disk with a small Python script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59816/discussion-between-xenoid-and-alexanoid).

Comment: thanks ! Did you mean original UTF-8 encoded twice or what ? I also would be really grateful if you can show how did you check the file name encoding in the WAR.. some command for CLI or what ?

Comment: A quick python script where everything is explained: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nr84lvrqadys87i/Russian-encoding.zip?dl=0)

Comment: This is probably caused by the [unzip-5.42-iso8859_2.patch](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/unzip/unzip-iso8859_2.patch?expand=1) from January, 2002 that pins iso8859-2 encoding for filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need package [unzip-rcc](https://software.opensuse.org/package/unzip-rcc?search_term=unzip-rcc). I have tested on my computer that if I use unzip-rcc, i will success. While if i use original unzip, it fails.

I am a Chinese user who also need Unicode. Every time i install openSUSE, this package is installed at a high priority. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, unzip is working fine but Tomcat still deploy(unzip) the files with an issue

Answer (score 1):

The WAR actually contains the file name encoded in UTF-8. However the flag that says so (bit #11 of the general purpose flags) is unset, but this is possible since the JAR command uses another variant of name encoding (this is actually the case with the JAR command I have).

So the real answer is: don't use a regular ZIP command to unpack but use the JAR command itself:

```
jar -xvf api.war
```

Yields:

```
created: WEB-INF/
created: WEB-INF/classes/
created: WEB-INF/classes/sample-data/
created: WEB-INF/classes/sample-data/decisions/
created: WEB-INF/classes/sample-data/decisions/novobudivy_refs/
inflated: WEB-INF/classes/sample-data/decisions/novobudivy_refs/13я-стац_я-великого-фонтану-1496338558663.xml
```